# Switched from .render() to .to_html() when using dataframe.style and now getting TypeError: cannot pickle 'module' object

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, typeerror

After creating a dataframe and styling it, I would originally use .render() to turn it into an html string. However, after switching it to .to_html() I am getting a type error.

After styling my dataframe I would turn it into an html string using .render(). However, I got a warning message:

```
FutureWarning: this method is deprecated in favour of `Styler.to_html()`
  return df_styled_without_date.render()
```

So I switched it to .to_html() and am now getting this error:

```
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py", line 1155, in to_html
    obj = self._copy(deepcopy=True)  # manipulate table_styles on obj, not self
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\style.py", line 1388, in _copy
    setattr(styler, attr, copy.deepcopy(val) if deepcopy else val)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 205, in _deepcopy_list
    append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 210, in _deepcopy_tuple
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 210, in <listcomp>
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 210, in _deepcopy_tuple
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 210, in <listcomp>
    y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 237, in _deepcopy_method
    return type(x)(x.__func__, deepcopy(x.__self__, memo))
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 172, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 270, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 230, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 172, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 270, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 230, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 172, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 270, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 230, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 172, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 270, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 230, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 172, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 270, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 230, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 161, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'module' object
```

Can anyone help? I'm stuck.

Comment: it sounds like there's something in the dataframe that it can't render. You need to post a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think the difference between `render` and `to_html` is that `to_html` first copies the styler object before rendering (to preserve the originals state). It would appear your dataframe contains an object that cannot be copied.